# Application throws 'NSInvalidArgumentException' when trying to cancel a local notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

My code throws the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

On the line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday];
```

In the code block:

```
if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dailyReminder"] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        //Schedule Notifications for each checked day
        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dailyReminderMonday"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            //Set up the local notification
            appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if(appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday){
                //Set fire date to alert time
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday.fireDate = mondayFireTime;
                //Set Alert body
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday.alertBody = textField.text;
                //Set time zone to default
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                //Repeat the notification everyday (fires at same time
                //as initial notification)
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

                // schedule notification
                UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                [app scheduleLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday];

                NSLog(@"Monday Fire Date: %@", appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday.fireDate);
            }
        }
        else {
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday]; 
        }

        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dailyReminderTuesday"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            //Set up the local notification
            appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if(appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday){
                //Set fire date to alert time
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday.fireDate = tuesdayFireTime;
                //Set Alert body
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday.alertBody = textField.text;
                //Set time zone to default
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                //Repeat the notification everyday (fires at same time
                //as initial notification)
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

                // schedule notification
                UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                [app scheduleLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday];

                NSLog(@"Tuesday Fire Date: %@", appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday.fireDate);
            }
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday]; 
        }

        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dailyReminderWednesday"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            //Set up the local notification
            appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if(appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday){
                //Set fire date to alert time
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday.fireDate = wednesdayFireTime;
                //Set Alert body
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday.alertBody = textField.text;
                //Set time zone to default
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                //Repeat the notification everyday (fires at same time
                //as initial notification)
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

                // schedule notification
                UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                [app scheduleLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday];

                NSLog(@"Wednesday Fire Date: %@", appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday.fireDate);
            }
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday]; 
        }

        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dailyReminderThursday"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            //Set up the local notification
            appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if(appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday){
                //Set fire date to alert time
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday.fireDate = thursdayFireTime;
                //Set Alert body
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday.alertBody = textField.text;
                //Set time zone to default
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                //Repeat the notification everyday (fires at same time
                //as initial notification)
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

                // schedule notification
                UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                [app scheduleLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday];

                NSLog(@"Thursday Fire Date: %@", appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday.fireDate);
            }
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday]; 
        }

        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dailyReminderFriday"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            //Set up the local notification
            appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if(appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday){
                //Set fire date to alert time
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday.fireDate = fridayFireTime;
                //Set Alert body
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday.alertBody = textField.text;
                //Set time zone to default
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                //Repeat the notification everyday (fires at same time
                //as initial notification)
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

                // schedule notification
                UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                [app scheduleLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday];

                NSLog(@"Friday Fire Date: %@", appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday.fireDate);
            }
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday]; 
        }

        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dailyReminderSaturday"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            //Set up the local notification
            appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if(appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday){
                //Set fire date to alert time
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday.fireDate = saturdayFireTime;
                //Set Alert body
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday.alertBody = textField.text;
                //Set time zone to default
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                //Repeat the notification everyday (fires at same time
                //as initial notification)
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

                // schedule notification
                UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                [app scheduleLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday];

                NSLog(@"Saturday Fire Date: %@", appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday.fireDate);
            }
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday]; 
        }

        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dailyReminderSunday"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            //Set up the local notification
            appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if(appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday){
                //Set fire date to alert time
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday.fireDate = sundayFireTime;
                //Set Alert body
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday.alertBody = textField.text;
                //Set time zone to default
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                //Repeat the notification everyday (fires at same time
                //as initial notification)
                appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

                // schedule notification
                UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                [app scheduleLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday];

                NSLog(@"Sunday Fire Date: %@", appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday.fireDate);
            }
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday]; 
        }


    }
    else {
        //Remove all daily notifications
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationTuesday];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationWednesday];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationThursday];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationFriday];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationSaturday];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationSunday];
    }
```

I also have this piece of code in my AppDelegate:

```
//Initialze daily notifications
        dailyNotificationMonday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        dailyNotificationTuesday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        dailyNotificationWednesday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        dailyNotificationThursday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        dailyNotificationFriday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        dailyNotificationSaturday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        dailyNotificationSunday = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

        //Initialize submition notifications
        submitNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        badgerNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

        //Initialize Automatic backup notification
        automaticBackupNotification  = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
```

Which is only called once when the application is first launched.

I'm not used to using local notifications at all, but I don't understand whats going on here, it seems to me like I'm trying to cancel a notification that doesn't exist?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Tysin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday` is `nil`. This doesn't seem to be a valid value to pass to `-cancelLocalNotification:`.

Have you tried:

```
if (appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

appDelegate.dailyNotificationMonday is nil because you only schedule it in this if block:

```
if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dailyReminderMonday"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
```

If that's not true and cancelLocalNotification is called in the else block, then you're essentially telling the app to cancel a notification that hasn't been scheduled yet. I actually think you don't even need that else block, did you try just getting rid of it?